# Why does std::optional::operator=(U&&) require U to be a non-scalar type?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17, option-type

For optional's `template<class U = T> optional<T>& operator=(U&& v);` the standard demands that (see [[optional.assign]/3.16](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/optional#assign-16)):

> This function shall not participate in overload resolution unless
>   ...
>   `conjunction_v<is_scalar<T>, is_same<T, decay_t<U>>>` is `false`
>   ...

Why do we have to exclude case when assigning a scalar of type `U == T`?

Comment: probably because then another overload is fine. Looking at a single overload doesnt really give you the full picture

Comment: Types are all special cases..., but fundamental types and void in particular are very boring!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This exists to support:

```
optional<int> o(42);
o = {}; // <== we want this to reset o
```

We have a bunch of [assignment overloads](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/operator%3D), which take:

1. `nullopt_t`
2. `optional const&`
3. `optional&&`
4. `U&&`
5. `optional<U> const&`
6. `optional<U>&&`

For scalars, specifically, #4 would be a standard conversion whereas anything else would be a user-defined conversion - so it would be the best match. However, the result of that would be assigning `o` to be engaged with a value of `0`. That would mean that `o = {}` could potentially mean different things depending on the type of `T`. Hence, we exclude scalars.

For non-scalars, #4 and #3 would be equivalent (both user-defined conversions), and #3 would win by being a non-template. No problem there.