# Initializing member variables with braces or parentheses

Tags: c++, c++11

When initializing member variables in a constructor you can do it in these two different ways, using braces or parentheses:

```
class some_class {

some_class(): foo{<value>}, bar(<value>) {}

T foo;
T bar;
};
```

Is there a functional difference between these two initialization methods, and if so, which one should I opt to use?

Comment: It's ultimately a tab-vs-spaces debate. Usually `foo{...}` and `foo(...)` are the same, and when they aren't, `foo{...}` will be the same as `foo({...})`.

Comment: Depends of `T`. for `T = std::vector<int>`, `foo{4, 5}` is a container with 2 items, whereas `foo(42, 0)` is a container with 42 items.

Comment: You might read [initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization) which explain the difference kind of initialization..

Comment: @Jarod42 That's a really good, succinct answer! If you want to post that as an actual answer I'd mark it as answered

Comment: Gory details provided a [Initialization - cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization) and here [Difference between S() vs S{}?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59887383/difference-between-s-vs-s)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between S() vs S{}?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59887383/difference-between-s-vs-s)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin no, I know of the differences between direct and list initialization, but I hadn't put together that you could do the same thing when constructing member variables in a constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends of `T`. for example with `[T = std::vector<int>]`,

`foo{4, 5}` is a container with 2 items (4 and 5),

whereas `foo(42, 0)` is a container with 42 items (with value 0).

You might read [initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization) which explains the different kind of initializations for further detail...